# Want help in jquery for finding imagebutton id and returning to ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am creating Dynamic table inside a div tag. Inside of each cell, a label and Imagebutton is added. Cell is added to row and row to table. I want to know how I can find which imagebuton in 5*8 table was clicked using jquery. Dynamic table code addition is in asp.net

```
public void DisplaySeatLayout()
{
        //fetching data from database     
        _seatBUS = new SeatBUS();
        DataTable dt = _seatBUS.GetAllSeatByBusRouter(_listBus);

        //Layout generation code    
        ImageButton img ;
        HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();
        table.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        table.Attributes.Add("id", "LayoutTable");

        HtmlTableRow [] tr = new HtmlTableRow[] { new HtmlTableRow(), new HtmlTableRow(), new HtmlTableRow(),new HtmlTableRow(),new HtmlTableRow()};
        HtmlTableCell tc = null;
        int SeatNo=0;
        //Getting Total no of seats.
        int MaxSeatNo = dt.Rows.Count;
        //Iterating datatable

            //Displaying labels for displaying column names in the table
            for (int columnCounter = 0; columnCounter < 8; columnCounter++){
                for (int rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < 5; rowCounter++){
                    if (SeatNo < MaxSeatNo){
                            if (rowCounter == 2 && columnCounter < 7){
                                //adding label in each cell.
                                tc = new HtmlTableCell();
                                Label lbl = new Label();
                                lbl.Text = "";
                                lbl.ID = "lbl " + rowCounter.ToString() + columnCounter.ToString();
                                  tc.Controls.Add(lbl);
                                tr[rowCounter].Controls.Add(tc);
                            }
                            else{
                                //adding label in each cell.
                                tc = new HtmlTableCell();
                                Label lbl = new Label();
                                lbl.Text = dt.Rows[SeatNo]["NumberSeat"].ToString();
                                lbl.ID = "lbl " + rowCounter.ToString() + columnCounter.ToString();
                                lbl.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                                tc.Controls.Add(lbl);
                                //adding imagebutton in each cell . 
                                img = new ImageButton();
                                img.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                                img.Attributes.Add("type", "image");

                                img.Attributes.Add("id", dt.Rows[SeatNo]["NumberSeat"].ToString());
                                img.CssClass = "seatRightMostRow1";
                                img.ImageUrl = "../Images/available_seat_img.png";
                                img.ID = dt.Rows[SeatNo]["NumberSeat"].ToString();

                                img.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(Imagebutton_Click);
                                tc.Controls.Add(img);
                                tr[rowCounter].Controls.Add(tc);
                                SeatNo++;
                            }
                    }//SeatNo < MaxSeatNo
                  table.Controls.Add(tr[rowCounter]);
                }
                seatArranngement.Controls.Add(table);
            }


}
```

DOM contents in HTML page.

```
            <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_seatArranngement">        

                     <table runat="server" id="LayoutTable">
<tr>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 00" runat="server">1</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_1" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="1" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 01" runat="server">5</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$5" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_5" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="5" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$5&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 02" runat="server">9</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$9" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_9" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="9" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$9&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 03" runat="server">13</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$13" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_13" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="13" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$13&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 04" runat="server">17</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$17" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_17" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="17" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$17&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 05" runat="server">21</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$21" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_21" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="21" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$21&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 06" runat="server">25</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$25" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_25" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="25" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$25&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 07" runat="server">29</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$29" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_29" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="29" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$29&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 10" runat="server">2</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_2" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="2" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$2&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 11" runat="server">6</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$6" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_6" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="6" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$6&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 12" runat="server">10</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$10" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_10" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="10" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$10&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 13" runat="server">14</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$14" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_14" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="14" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$14&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 14" runat="server">18</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$18" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_18" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="18" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$18&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 15" runat="server">22</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$22" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_22" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="22" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$22&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 16" runat="server">26</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$26" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_26" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="26" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$26&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 17" runat="server">30</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$30" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_30" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="30" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$30&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 20"></span></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 21"></span></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 22"></span></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 23"></span></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 24"></span></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 25"></span></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 26"></span></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 27" runat="server">31</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$31" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_31" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="31" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$31&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 30" runat="server">3</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$3" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_3" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="3" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$3&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 31" runat="server">7</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$7" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_7" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="7" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$7&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 32" runat="server">11</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$11" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_11" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="11" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$11&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 33" runat="server">15</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$15" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_15" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="15" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$15&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 34" runat="server">19</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$19" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_19" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="19" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$19&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 35" runat="server">23</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$23" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_23" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="23" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$23&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 36" runat="server">27</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$27" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_27" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="27" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$27&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 37" runat="server">32</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$32" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_32" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="32" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$32&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 40" runat="server">4</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$4" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_4" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="4" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$4&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 41" runat="server">8</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$8" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_8" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="8" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$8&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 42" runat="server">12</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$12" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_12" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="12" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$12&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 43" runat="server">16</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$16" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_16" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="16" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$16&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 44" runat="server">20</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$20" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_20" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="20" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$20&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 45" runat="server">24</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$24" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_24" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="24" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$24&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 46" runat="server">28</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$28" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_28" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="28" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$28&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
    <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl 47" runat="server">33</span><input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$33" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_33" class="seatRightMostRow1" runat="server" type="image" id="33" src="../Images/available_seat_img.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$33&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Without seeing any actual code, I'm not sure we can be much help.  You can identify an element with jQuery using any number of DOM selectors.  What does your DOM look like and what selector are you currently using?  What does that selector find?

Comment: Ok, you've shown us your server-side code.  However, jQuery (JavaScript in general) runs on the client-side.  The two are entirely disconnected from one another.  Your jQuery code is looking at the rendered HTML, so you'll need to know what that looks like.  Essentially, ASP.NET has nothing to do with what you're asking.

Comment: Well in that case I can change table to be displayed at client side, instead of server side control

Comment: The interesting part now is that your `input` elements already have click event handlers which appear to be performing some sort of post-back.  What exactly are you trying to do via jQuery?  If clicking one of these elements posts back the whole page then there won't be much that JavaScript can do for you since the page will be abandoned for the new server response.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach to all buttons in the table with:

```
$("#<%= LayoutTable.ClientID %>").find("input[type='image']").click(function(e) {
   //Do something here
});
```

Comment: getting error like . Error 2 An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.ClientID.get' D:\Bus Online\eProject\WebBusTicket\Admin\Pages\Booking.aspx 32

Comment: Wait, is `LayoutTable` a server-side identifier or a client-side identifier?  Looking at the code again, it looks client-side.  So maybe this instead: `$('#LayoutTable').find...`

Comment: thanks..it worked now .. but can I return the selected image's ID to asp code?

Comment: LayoutTable is a server-side identifier, which this approach works for me.  Every control that posts back should be accessible through `Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET")`, and the argument parameters via `Request.Form.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT")`.  So you wouldn't even need to use JQuery for that.  But if you wanted to use JQuery, add a server-side hidden field control `<asp:HiddenField id="X" runat="server" />`, and use JQuery to write the ID of the control to that hidden.